# Why After Advice is getting print before method call

Tags: java, annotations, aop, spring-aop, aspect

MY Spring AOP programm is not working as Expected.
I created simple AOP annotation program below but the output is not what I thought.

Programm :

Beans.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:aop = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

 <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>


 <bean id="student"  class="com.surajhome.practice.spring.Student" >
    <property name="name" value="Suraj Kudale"></property>
    <property name="age" value="27"></property>
 </bean>  

  <bean id="logging" class="com.surajhome.practice.spring.Logging"></bean>


 </beans>
```

Student.java

package com.surajhome.practice.spring;

```
public class Student {

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    String name;
    int age;



}
```

Logging.Java

```
package com.surajhome.practice.spring;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class Logging {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.surajhome.practice.spring.*.*(..) )")
    public void selectAll()
    {

    }
    @After("selectAll()")
    public void afterAdvice()
    {
        System.out.println("After Advice called");
    }

    @Before("selectAll()")
    public void beforeAdvice()
    {
        System.out.println("Before Advice called");
    }

    public void afterReturningAdvice()
    {
        System.out.println("After Returning Advice called");
    }

    public void afterThrowingException()
    {
        System.out.println("After Exception Advice called");
    }

}
```

MainApp.java

```
package com.surajhome.practice.spring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext appContext=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

        Student std=(Student) appContext.getBean("student");


        System.out.println(std.getName());
        System.out.println(std.getAge());

    }
}
```

output :

Before Advice called
After Advice called
Suraj Kudale
Before Advice called
After Advice called
27

It should be :
Before Advice called
Suraj Kudale
After Advice called
Before Advice called
27
After Advice called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the flow that happens when you call the  `System.out.println(std.getName());`, first @Before method of the get name is called then get name returns a value and @After is called only then System.out.println gets the string and prints it

Comment: Ohh Yes I got it Thanks 

I should write like this: 

public String getName() {
      System.out.println("Name : " + name );
      return name;
   }

Comment: Or you just let **(a)** an `@AfterReturning` advice or **(b)** an `@Around` advice print the result.